# How to prove ◻(ϕ → ψ) → (♢ϕ → ♢ψ) a theorem of the normal modal logic S5?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I feel like this is the inversion of logic 5, so my intuition is that we cannot prove it a theorem of logic 5... But I am not sure at all

Answer (score 1):

That formula is actually a theorem of K. It can be proved as follows:

```
1. □(φ → ψ)               Assumption. 
2. □(¬ψ → ¬φ)             From 1, by the N rule. 
3. □¬ψ → □¬φ              From 2, by axiom K. 
4. ¬◇ψ → ¬◇φ              From 3, by equivalence of □ and ¬◇¬
5. ◇φ → ◇ψ                From 4, by contraposition. 
6. □(φ → ψ) → (◇φ → ◇ψ)   From 1 and 6, discharging the assumption.
```

Comment: Hi Bumble, thanks a lot for your answer! But in fact, I am asked to argue if it is a theorem of S5. So can I say if it is a theorem of K it is not a theorem of S5?

Comment: All theorems of K are theorems of S5, since K is the most fundamental of the modal logics created by C I Lewis. Or, to put it another way, S5 contains all the theorems of K. So this formula is a theorem of S5 and all other extensions of K.