# How to prove that: ⊢/k ◻p v ◻¬p

Tags: logic, modal-logic

My though it that we can refer to completeness. So just argue that  ◻p v  ◻¬p does not have a corresponding model. But I am not sure...

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! Unfortunately, I think this question would be better on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), since there is no philosophical issue raised here. Same for [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97106/how-to-prove-%e2%97%bb%cf%95-%e2%86%92-%cf%88-%e2%86%92-%cf%95-%e2%86%92-%cf%88-a-theorem-of-the-normal-modal-logic-s5).

Comment: Yes. We don't do logic here.

Comment: I think you would be wasting your time asking this on Math.SE since mathematicians typically do not use modal logic, while philosophers do. The formula □P ∨ □¬P is not a theorem of K. It has a countermodel when there is an accessible possible world in which P holds, and another in which ¬P holds. The formula is a theorem in the system that Hughes and Cresswell call Triv.

Comment: @Bumble Mathematicians do indeed [modal logic on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-logic). However, I grant you it is not mainstream, so I am not sure how to proceed in this case. Sorry about the last comment, it was a bit rude.

Comment: @irecorsan No problem. Actually I am aware of published papers on modal logic by mathematicians. But most mathematicians who have not studied logic at graduate level tend not to be familiar with it and often are not even aware of it. By contrast, it is often taught at undergraduate level to philosophers. For example, Restall and Standefer's "Logical Methods" is an introductory text book aimed at philosophy students and includes modal logic right from the get-go.